# How to use Guzzle HTTP Post method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, guzzle6, guzzle

I'm building a small application in `Laravel 5.4` where I'm facing difficulties in API calls through `GuzzleHttp`, I'm trying to call a `route` in my `api.php`:

```
Route::post('/request', 'HomeController@getRequest');
```

and in my controller I'm calling:

```
public function __construct(GuzzleHttp\Client $client)
{
    $this->client = $client;
}

public function getRequest( Request $request)
{
    $request = $this->client->post($request->url, [$request->request_data]);
    $response = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($request->getBody());
    return response()->json(['data' => json_decode($response->d)], $request->getStatusCode());
}
```

The data value set which I'm inserting:

```
{"url":"http://demo.conxn.co.in/CoxnsvcA.svc/Login","request_data":{"username":"********","password":"*******","client_secret_key":"rybbdk23dsaxxmYTHJKFHJSKksdfljsdf"}}
```

And I'm getting error:

[image: error description]

But while using through postman API tester, I'm getting appropriate results.

[image: Appropriate results through postman API checker]

Help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting JSON data in wrong way, you can use built in JSON option that is used to easily upload JSON encoded data as the body of a request. A Content-Type header of application/json will be added if no Content-Type header is already present on the message.

You can find more details here http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json

Here is your updated code

```
public function __construct(GuzzleHttp\Client $client)
{
$this->client = $client;
}

public function getRequest( Request $request)
{
   $request = $this->client->post($request->url,GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON =>[$request>request_data]);
   $response = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($request->getBody());
   return response()->json(['data' => json_decode($response->d)],$request->getStatusCode());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with this method

```
public function getRequest(Request $request)
    {
      $client = New GuzzleHttpClient();

       $input = $request->all();
       unset($input['_token']);


       //Post to server
       $request = $client->request('POST','url',[
        'form_params' => [

       'inputcontent' => $input['inputcontent'],
        ]
        ]);
```